# Go precise decimals with mgo

Tags: go

I am writing an application where I use money and want very accurate numbers. I am also using mgo to store the results after some application. I was wondering if there was a way for me to use `math.Rat` or godec in a struct and have it store as a number in mgo?

This is the kind of code i was hoping to run:

```
package main

import(
  "fmt"
  "math/big"
  "labix.org/v2/mgo"
)

var mgoSession *mgo.Session

type Test struct{
  Budget big.Rat
}

func MongoLog(table string, pointer interface{}) {
  err := mgoSession.DB("db_log").C(table).Insert(pointer)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}

func main(){
  var err error
  mgoSession, err = mgo.Dial("localhost:27017")
  defer mgoSession.Close()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  cmp := big.NewRat(1, 100000)
  var test = Test{Budget : *big.NewRat(5, 10)}
  MongoLog("test", &test)
  for i := 0; i < 20; i++{
    fmt.Printf("Printf: %s\n", test.Budget.FloatString(10))
    fmt.Println("Println:", test.Budget, "\n")
    test.Budget.Sub(&test.Budget, cmp)
//    test.Budget = test.Budget - cpm
  }
  MongoLog("test", &test)
}
```

Comment: And you code does not run because...?

Comment: because the mongo db doesn't know how to store a big.Rat

Comment: you can just store the "STRING" representation of the Big Number

Comment: take a look to https://github.com/shopspring/decimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`big.Rat` is basically a pair of unexported <strike>`int`</strike> `big.Int` values describing the numerator and denominator of a rational number, respectively.

You can easily get both numbers through `(*big.Rat).Denom` and `(*big.Rat).Num`.

Then store them in a structure of your own, with exported (upper case) fields:

```
type CurrencyValue struct {
    Denom int64
    Num   int64
}
```

Store this with `mgo` and convert it back to a `*big.Rat` in your application through `big.NewRat`

**Edit:**

Nick Craig-Wood in the comments correctly noted that `big.Rat` actually consists of 2 `big.Int` values, not `int` values as I had written (easy to miss the upper case i). It's hard to represent a `big.Int` in BSON but, `int64` should cover most use-cases.

Comment: `big.Rat` is a pair of `big.Int`s with unlimited precision, so may not fit into the `int`s in the `CurrencyValue` struct. I'd have to disagree with @Rick-777 - `big.Rat`s have unlimited precision not 32 bit.